# SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata accepting invalid terms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, managed-metadata

I currently have a problem regarding our Managed metadata field. At this point, our field is accepting invalid terms in the term set but is a valid term in the term store. Below are screenshots that would further explain:

**This is my current setup for my term store**

[image]

**The 2nd image shows the new item in the list, the alliance field points to the Alliances term set.**

[image]

**In this 3rd image, I've entered the term coming from the 'Industries' term store. It did "validate" by the red colored text font.**

[image]

**but when you press the save, it saves successfully.**

[image]

I believe this shouldn't be the case and I'm not sure as to why this is the behavior and if this is indeed a known bug for managed metadata. Let me know if you need more information. Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Do you have Closed or Open Submission Policy?  If it's open the new value will be added to the term store

Comment: I think Tomasz spotted it right!

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I have a closed submission policy.

Answer (score 0):

probably moot at this point but for anyone who comes across this, "Alliances" above is not a term set.  "Information Technology" is part of the same term set as Alliances ("Test Term Set").